# Data storage on the client-side in Angular apps

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular and TypeScript and I can't understand one moment.
I have two classes, for example, Employee and Department.
I created models and Many-To-One relation between my entities on the server-side with sequelize:

```
db.employee.belongsTo(db.department, {foreignKey: 'emp_depID'});
db.department.hasMany(db.employee);
```

I declared foreignKey like 'emp_depID' in the employee table, which references to department's id in the department table. So, on the client-side, I have the same structure, as in the my model tables:

```
export interface Employee {
    id?: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    emp_depID: number;
}

export interface Department {
    id?: number;
    depName: string;
}
```

Is this correct to use emp_depID just like a number?

Comment: yes, this should be correct.  are you having problems with it?

Comment: No, everything is good. I just wanted to know that this is a correct structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your Department's `id` is optional? I think it must have an required id as a primary key. So remove the optional part from it

```
export interface Department {
    id: number;
    depName: string;
}
```

And the foreign key `emp_depID` must be a number, because it is related to the `id` of the Department which is also a number.

Comment: Department's id is optional, because it's  AUTO_INCREMENT in my model. Thanks!

Comment: Auto_increment is not related to the identity column. id is an identity column

Comment: Yes, now I understand you